# Why this is no insertion of string into the set as I have created?

Tags: c++, insert, set

```
#include <iostream>

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void unique_Subsequences(string str, int indx, string newstring , unordered_set<string> st){
   
    if(indx == str.size()){
        if(st.count(newstring)){
            
            return;
        }
        else{
             st.insert(newstring);
             cout<<newstring<<endl;
             return;
        }
    }
    
    for(auto i : st) cout<<i<<endl;
    unique_Subsequences(str, indx+1,newstring+str[indx],st);
    unique_Subsequences(str, indx+1, newstring,st);
    
}

int main()
{
    
cout<<"Enter the string :";

    string str;

    cin>>str;

    unordered_set<string> st;

    unique_Subsequences(str,0,"",st);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: `cin>>str;` -- Please initialize `str` with the data you are using.  There is no need for `cin` here.  Just `str = "The data that is giving the issue";`

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass reference to the set, not a copy,
so change this

```
void unique_Subsequences(..., unordered_set<string> st)
```

to this:

```
void unique_Subsequences(..., unordered_set<string>& st)
```